# Error while saving custom module

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9 version. Created the custom module. I tried to save details. I got this error.

> A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store.

how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check following:

1. Check your model class
2. This error comes from **app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Resource/Block.php** _beforeSave method. I think you try to save data in 'cms_block' table.
3. cms_block check unique identifier for store.

Comment: Thanks @Sohel. I having this code in my model. 

if (!$this->getIsUniqueBlockToStores($object)) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store.'));
        }.

 What is the mistake here.

Comment: Can you show your resource model class code?

Comment: I solved this. There was a condition to check prod ids but checking of category ids are missing there. Now works fine. Thanks @Sohel.